# Running Gulp task one after another in specific order

Tags: javascript, gulp

I need to run one gulp task that contains 3 or 4 another tasks. The problem is (steps):

1. In task #1 I need download file from remote server
2. After download completed, I need to run task #2
3. And when task #2 is done I need to run task #3

This is my code:

```js
var gulp       = require('gulp'),
    decompress = require('gulp-decompress'),
    download   = require("gulp-download"),
    ftp        = require('gulp-ftp'),
    gutil      = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('default', function(){
    console.log("Hello gulp");
});

var src_download = [
    "https://wordpress.org/latest.zip"
];

gulp.task('download', function(){
    download(src_download)
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./"));
});

gulp.task('unzip-wp', function(){
    return gulp.src('latest.zip')
    .pipe(decompress({strip: 1}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

gulp.task('install', ['download', 'unzip-wp']);
```

As you can see, when I am trying to run 'install' task - it will run 'unzip-wp' before 'download' has been completed...

What am I doing wrong?

I need to run 'unzip-wp' task only after 'download' task has been completed.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some example please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have the 'unzip-wp' task wait for the 'download' task to finish. To make sure the 'download' task is really finished also add a return statement to that task, i.e. this would do what you're looking for:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    decompress = require('gulp-decompress'),
    download = require("gulp-download"),
    ftp = require('gulp-ftp'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    console.log("Hello gulp");
});

var src_download = [
    "https://wordpress.org/latest.zip"
];

gulp.task('download', function () {
    return download(src_download)
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./"));
});

gulp.task('unzip-wp', ['download'], function () {
    return gulp.src('latest.zip')
        .pipe(decompress({strip: 1}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

gulp.task('install', ['unzip-wp']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple there is no need of unzip task it will also unzip into wordpress folder for the sake that it will not mess your other files.

```
gulp.task('download', function(){
    download(src_download)
    .pipe(decompress({strip: 1}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wordpress'));
});


gulp.task('default', ['download']);
```